# MERGE without specifying column names in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was looking at the `MERGE` command which seems cool but still it requires the columns to be specified. I'm looking for something like:

```
MERGE INTO target AS t
USING source AS s          
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
    [all t.fields = s.fields]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT ([all fields])
      VALUES ([all s.fields])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the issue that you don't want to type the column names, or that the tables are constantly changing?

Comment: **No** - you must spell out the columns to be set and what values they should be set to. No way around that...

Comment: somehow I couldn't reply to individual posts.

1. to Aaron Bertrand - I just don't want to type the columns.
2. to kuru kuru pa - I don't know how to try it.
3. to marc_s - thanks, if that is the case then I don't have a choice but to type the columns.

Comment: To avoid typing the columns, find the table in Object Explorer, expand the table name, then drag the [Columns] folder onto the query window. This will yield a comma-separated list of all the column names, all you have to do is format it (and remove columns you don't want to specify).

Comment: well, its not being lazy, I just want to learn stuffs to make development easy. I always find stuffs that's easy and proper than what I usually do.

Comment: @gangt: if you can't stand typing all those columns - get yourself a little helper tool, like [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) or [Red-Gate SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) that will allow you to use `SELECT *<TAB>` and thus expand the `*` into a list of all columns for that table. Very handy!

Comment: @gangt this is actually possible... If you still haven't found the answer.  It's like INSERT INTO Select * from inserted...or something...I saw it once and didn't bookmark it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not everything you wanted, but partially:

`WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN`
`INSERT`<s>`([all fields])`</s>
`VALUES (field1, field2, ...)`

(The values list has to be complete, and match the order of the fields in your table's definition.)

Comment: I got the point, basically it works like normal INSERT and UPDATE statements, no way around it. Thats fine.

Comment: @gangt -- it was a very good question, I'm glad you asked it. Despite what others may have said, "laziness" is a virtue in many ways when it comes to programming.  Whenever less typing translates to less work and fewer mistakes, we call that "increased efficiency", not "lazy".  So good job.

Comment: @kuru I'm not so sure in certain cases. There isn't a whole lot of typing involved here - just drag the column list from Object Explorer. And explicitly listing the column names in the code prevents debugging nightmares later, when the table structure changes (column is added, etc). You could argue the reverse is true (e.g. a column is removed) but the former is a much more common scenario.

Comment: @Aaron -- it wasn't wrong of the OP to ask...  I tend to share your technical opinion in general about the benefits of listing the columns, but regardless, that's a critique of TSQL in general (e.g., why it lets you not list them in certain cases, and forces you to list them in others), not the OP personally.  Also, there *could* be cases where it would not risk the problems you mention -- we don't know from the limited info the OP provided.  The hot-headed garbage (HLGEM calling the OP lazy and unprofessional just for asking the question) isn't in any way constructive to SO.

Comment: @kuru I agree, I just disagree with the generalization that less typing always translates to increased efficiency. Yes, there are cases where that holds true, but there are cases when you're just deferring the payment until later, and later might be at 3AM when a deployment causes the system to be down.

Comment: @Aaron -- you're preaching to the choir.  I didn't make the generalization ("less typing ***always***...) -- I said "Whenever less typing translates to less work and fewer mistakes..."  Anyway, you're right -- it's good advice, offered objectively.

Answer (score 18):

I'm lazy... this is a cheap proc I wrote that will spit out a general MERGE command for a table.  It queries information_schema.columns for column names.  I ripped out my source database name - so, you have to update the proc to work with your database (look for @SourceDB... I said it was cheap.)  Anyway, I know others could write it much better - it served my purpose well.  (It makes a couple assumptions that you could put logic in to handle - namely turning IDENTITY_INSERT OFF - even when a table doesn't have identity columns.)  It updates the table in your current context.  It was written against sql server 2008 to sync up some tables.  Use at your own risk, of course.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateMergeSQL]
    @TableName varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    declare @sql varchar(5000),@SourceInsertColumns varchar(5000),@DestInsertColumns varchar(5000),@UpdateClause varchar(5000)
    declare @ColumnName varchar(100), @identityColName varchar(100)
    declare @IsIdentity int,@IsComputed int, @Data_Type varchar(50)

    declare @SourceDB as varchar(200)


    -- source/dest i.e. 'instance.catalog.owner.' - table names will be appended to this
    -- the destination is your current db context
    set @SourceDB = '[mylinkedserver].catalog.myDBOwner.'

    set @sql = ''
    set @SourceInsertColumns  = ''
    set @DestInsertColumns  = ''
    set @UpdateClause  = ''
    set @ColumnName  = ''
    set @isIdentity = 0
    set @IsComputed = 0
    set @identityColName  = ''
    set @Data_Type  = ''


DECLARE @ColNames CURSOR
SET @ColNames = CURSOR FOR 
    select column_name, COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') as IsIdentity ,
        COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsComputed') as IsComputed , DATA_TYPE
    from information_schema.columns where table_name = @TableName order by ordinal_position

OPEN @ColNames
FETCH NEXT FROM @ColNames INTO @ColumnName, @isIdentity, @IsComputed, @DATA_TYPE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        if @IsComputed = 0 and @DATA_TYPE <> 'timestamp'
        BEGIN
            set @SourceInsertColumns = @SourceInsertColumns + 
                case when @SourceInsertColumns = '' THEN '' ELSE ',' end +
                'S.' + @ColumnName

            set @DestInsertColumns = @DestInsertColumns + 
                case when @DestInsertColumns = '' THEN '' ELSE ',' end +
                @ColumnName

            if @isIdentity = 0
            BEGIN
                set @UpdateClause = @UpdateClause + 
                case when @UpdateClause = '' THEN '' ELSE ',' end
                 + @ColumnName + ' = ' + 'S.' + @ColumnName + char(10)
            END

            if @isIdentity = 1 set @identityColName = @ColumnName
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @ColNames INTO @ColumnName, @isIdentity, @IsComputed, @DATA_TYPE
    END

CLOSE @ColNames
DEALLOCATE @ColNames

    SET @sql = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' ON;
            MERGE ' + @TableName + ' AS D
                USING ' + @SourceDB + @TableName + ' AS S
                ON (D.' + @identityColName + ' = S.' + @identityColName + ')
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
                THEN INSERT(' + @DestInsertColumns + ') 
                VALUES(' + @SourceInsertColumns + ')
            WHEN MATCHED 
                THEN UPDATE SET 
                    ' + @UpdateClause + '
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
                THEN DELETE
            OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*;
            SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TableName + ' OFF'

    Print @SQL

END
```

Comment: Definitely customized the script a bit more on my end, but this is great! 6 years later and this is still helping people..

Answer (score 2):

Simple alternative to merge without naming any fields or having to update statement whenever table design changes.  This is uni-directional from source to target, but it can be made bi-directional.  Only acts on changed records, so it is very fast even with linked servers on slower connection.

```
--Two statement run as transaction batch
DELETE
    C
FROM
    productschina C
    JOIN 
    (select * from productschina c except select * from productsus) z
    on c.productid=z.productid

INSERT into productschina select * from productsus except select * from productschina
```

Here is code to setup tables to test above:

```
--Create a target table
--drop table ProductsUS
CREATE TABLE ProductsUS
(
ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName VARCHAR(100),
Rate MONEY
) 
GO
--Insert records into target table
INSERT INTO ProductsUS
VALUES
(1, 'Tea', 10.00),
(2, 'Coffee', 20.00),
(3, 'Muffin', 30.00),
(4, 'Biscuit', 40.00)
GO
--Create source table
--drop table productschina
CREATE TABLE ProductsChina
(
ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName VARCHAR(100),
Rate MONEY
) 
GO
--Insert records into source table
INSERT INTO ProductsChina
VALUES
(1, 'Tea', 10.00),
(2, 'Coffee', 25.00),
(3, 'Muffin', 35.00),
(5, 'Pizza', 60.00)
GO
SELECT * FROM ProductsUS
SELECT * FROM ProductsChina
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer deserves a little more love.  It's simple, elegant and works.  However, depending on the tables in question, it may be a little bit slow because the except clause is evaluating every column.

I suspect you can save a little bit of time by just joining on the primary key and the last modified date (if one exists).

```
DELETE
    C
FROM
    productschina C
    JOIN 
    (select primary_key, last_mod_date from productschina c except select primary_key, last_mod_date from productsus) z
    on c.productid=z.productid

INSERT into productschina select * from productsus except select * from productschina
```